# Suggestions in popover for NSTokenField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstokenfield

I'm trying to subclass NSTokenField to show a popover with token suggestions.

I set my subclass as the super delegate, I intercept the `– tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem:` delegate method and return nil to prevent the menu from showing. It works fine except by returning nil the token field doesn't complete the string entered by the user.

Currently I'm using the following lines in `– tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem:` to add the suggested string:

```
NSText *editingText = [[self window] fieldEditor:NO forObject:self];
NSString *suggestionString = [filteredStrings objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *missingPart = [(NSString *)suggestionString substringFromIndex:[substring length]];
NSUInteger insertionPoint = [editingText selectedRange].location;
NSMutableString *currentStringPlusSuggestionString = [[editingText string] mutableCopy];
[currentStringPlusSuggestionString insertString:missingPart atIndex:insertionPoint];
[editingText setString:[stringWithSuggestionString copy]];
```

Unfortunately it generates an error when I try to insert text between 2 tokens. Here is the error but I don't really understand why the string is out of bounds.

```
[NSBigMutableString _getBlockStart:end:contentsEnd:forRange:stopAtLineSeparators:]: Range or index out of bounds'

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88835716 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8adae470 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff888354ec +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8efd6627 -[NSString _getBlockStart:end:contentsEnd:forRange:stopAtLineSeparators:] + 157
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8bd37c6f _NSFastFillAllLayoutHolesForGlyphRange + 285
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8bd008fa -[NSLayoutManager textContainerForGlyphAtIndex:effectiveRange:] + 238
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8bb4a18f -[NSTextView(NSSharing) didChangeText] + 194
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8bbe00ee -[NSTokenFieldCell textView:willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRange:toCharacterRange:] + 776
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8bd32795 -[NSControl textView:willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRange:toCharacterRange:] + 112
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8bd30724 -[NSTextView(NSSharing) setSelectedRanges:affinity:stillSelecting:] + 1076
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bcf8438 -[NSLayoutManager textStorage:edited:range:changeInLength:invalidatedRange:] + 406
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bcf828a -[NSTextStorage _notifyEdited:range:changeInLength:invalidatedRange:] + 154
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bda0f75 -[NSTextStorage processEditing] + 202
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8bc02c54 -[NSTextStorage endEditing] + 79
14  PopoverTokenField                   0x0000000100002f55 -[JSTokenField tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem:] + 1013
```

Alternatively, does anyone know another way to let the token field complete the string without having the menu?

Comment: I ran into this bug too.. I ended up moving the editing string to the end of the tokens array to workaround it